# Passing <p:inputText> values to Bean using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am having the `h:inputText` which having a text and by ajax request how can i send it's values to `bean` class and the values will be validated in further action begin at bean class ..

**view page code is**

```
<h:form>  
<p:panel id="panel" header="Login Panel" style="margin:0 auto;width:350px;margin-top:15%;">  
      <p:panelGrid columns="3"  id="pgrid1" styleClass="theme"  >  
          <p:outputLabel  value="User Name:" />  
          <p:inputText id="name" value="#{loginBean.name}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Name is required">
               <f:ajax event="blur" render="label" listener="loginBean.validateName" ></f:ajax>
               <!--Here the ajax event working properly but how can i get the inputText value when ajax event  is invoked-->
           </p:inputText>  
           <p:message for="name"  style="color: red;" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton type="Submit" value="Submit" action="#{loginBean.validate}" update="pgrid1"  />
</p:panel>
```

**My Bean class Code  is :**

```
 public void validateName(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) 
{
    //Here i need inputText value..how can i handle this task..!!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF has already set the `#{loginBean.name}` value at that moment. Just access it directly.

```
public void validateName(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println(name); // Look, JSF has already set it.
    // ... 
}
```

You've by the way an EL syntax error in `<f:ajax listener>` which causes the listener method never to be invoked, but I'll bet it to be just carelessness during preparing the question as you mentioned that it is "working properly". In the future questions, please edit code in the real development environment and copypaste real working code instead of blindly editing the code in the question editor.

Comment: In my question i have mentioned that the `ajax` listener working for only `render` the `label` .. but in my bean class when i print the `name` as you mentioned above , it return `null`

Comment: Here i used the  `ajax` listener when the mouse leave the `inputText` field.. so i typed some content in `textField` and when i click 'tap' ,, it should be called `ajax` method in bean ,but it didn't invoke 'listener'.. i dont know why it is happening..